# Shanghai sites for an avid woodworker?

Tags: shanghai

I will be in Shanghai for two weeks.  I'm an avid woodworker, who enjoys making all sorts of stuff (I've dalied into laser cutters, 3d printing, etc).

Does anyone know of any sites in Shanghai that might be interesting for me to visit?  Shops selling carpentry tools, museums dedicated to historical construction, temple construction, etc.

Unfortunately, my visit ends before the Shanghai International Furniture Machinery Fair in September...